# What are 'foo' and 'bar' in the following script and do they need to be defined?

Tags: javascript

It's *just* a sample code:

```
  function process(elements) {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].value) {
        total++;
      }
    }
    if (total) {
      return {
        foo: 'Wow!'
      };
    } else {
      return {
        foo: 'Great!',
        bar: 'Bravo!'
      };
    }
  }
```

Are `foo` and `bar` called *properties*? And do they need to be declared, like:

```
var foo;
var bar;
```

Comment: They are *property names* and no they do not have to be declared as variables.

Comment: ...Because this syntax `foo: ...` and `bar:....` is how an object property is declared.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a long tradition of using foo and bar as example names.. when you see foo or bar, think this is just an example..

Comment: Feel free to also use foo and bar in talk about code.. as in I really foobared the code on that project..

Comment: Yes. No. Do you know what properties are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines like

```
  return {
    foo: 'Great!',
    bar: 'Bravo!'
  };
```

are returning an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) that is initialized on the fly using the [initializer notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

> Objects can be initialized using new Object(), Object.create(), or using the literal notation (initializer notation). An object initializer is a comma-delimited list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}).

So `foo` and `bar` are property names and therefor don't need to be declared with `var`.

> The terms foobar (/ˈfuːbɑːr/), or foo and others are used as placeholder names (also referred to as metasyntactic variables) in computer programming or computer-related documentation.[1] They have been used to name entities such as variables, functions, and commands whose exact identity is unimportant and serve only to demonstrate a concept.

You can read more about history and etymology on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).